# Is it possible to get the access token of an app you have accepted on your own profile?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Say I accept an app called "HelloWorld", is there any way to get the token that has been granted for the creators of "HelloWorld"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends whether the app allows client side authentication. All you will need is the redirect_uri and client_id (App id)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
  &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
  &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
  &response_type=token
```

The token returned will be the same token granted to the app as long as it hasn't expired or token has been revoked from authorization.

Whether you should actually do this is a next thing altogether. I am just stating the possibility exists.

Comment: Thank you, worked great. And you are right, there is no legitimate reason for anyone to do this.